# c# Ternary operator

Tags: c#, if-statement, error-handling, ternary-operator

I am working on a an application that has no documentation (although the code is quite clear and well-written) and I am trying to write some useful technical documentation for the next guy who comes along after I am in a mental hospital.

In the web-service method, if the call to the web-service returns an error, then the *Catch* code runs to increment the number of retries for the message and set the MessageStatus to "New" (so that it is retried if less than 5) or "Error" (for unknown errors), but there is one line I am not completely sure of and I need to document this process properly:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
int NoRetries = (int)dRow[(int)Common.OutboundSQLFields.Message_Retries];
string messageStatus = (NoRetries < 5) ? Common.MessageStatus(ex) : "Expired";
    ...
```

Does this mean that if the `NoRetries` is greater than 4, then the *MessageStatus* will be set to **Expired**, else the method *Common.MessageStatus* will be called to reset the string *MessageStatus* based on the value of `(ex)` ?

So to make it more self-describing, could I rewrite that Ternary operator code as:

```
string MessageStatus="";
If (NoRetries > 4)
    {
    MessageStatus = "Expired";
    }
else
    {
    MessageStatus = Common.MessageStatus(ex);
    }
```

Comment: *could I rewrite that Ternary operator code as...* - did you try?

Comment: yes, your rewritten code is correct

Comment: Yes you can, although I see no value in this. I would even remove the parenthesis around NoRetries < 5

Comment: @AntP: yes, and it works, but I was also trying to get confirmation of my understanding so I can document it properly.

Comment: *"Does this mean that if the NoRetries is greater than 4, then the MessageStatus will be set to Expired, else the method Common.MessageStatus will be called to reset the string MessageStatus based on the value of (ex) ?"*. Yes.

Comment: @OurManInBananas Your unit tests should have told you that changing the code resulted in the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(Statement) ? TRUE : FALSE`

So if `NoRetries < 5` then `Common.MessageStatus(ex)`
if `NoRetries >= 5` then `"Expired"`

Hope this clarifies it :)

Comment: And if NoRetries == 5?

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to test for smaller or equal to 5 you would have to write (NoRetries <=5) otherwise only 1-4 will return TRUE

Answer (score 1):

As the statement is:

```
string messageStatus = (NoRetries < 5) ? Common.MessageStatus(ex) : "Expired";
```

It should be like:

```
string MessageStatus="";
if (NoRetries < 5)
    MessageStatus = Common.MessageStatus(ex);
else
    MessageStatus = "Expired";
```

You reversed it actually. But your's is correct too.